# Having trouble accessing nested data and Nil in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, data-structures, null

I'm getting data from an external API in my Rails app for a React frontend. I'd like to cleanup the data before it hits the frontend and trying to reach nested data in a unpredictable API response. Sometimes the nested data returns something and other times `nil`. This is the problem (I think).

I've tried various protections with conditions but this doesn't seem to work.

Here is the method I'm working with:

```
def song_details
    search = HTTParty.get("https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release/#{params[:songId]}?inc=artist-credits+artist-rels+media+recording-level-rels+url-rels+work-level-rels+recording-rels&fmt=json", {
      headers: {"User-Agent" => "Songly/ver 1.0", "Contact" => "demiansims@gmail.com"}
      })


end
```

If I call `search['relations'][0]['artist']['name']` in Rails Console, I get a nice string of a name back.

If I try to run:

```
search['relations'].map { |r| r['artist'].each { |a| puts a['name'] }}
```

I get `no method for Nil class on []` error. I know it's because some of the values are Nil.

Here is a full picture of the nested data (1 iteration worth - there are about 20 of these):

```
{"end"=>nil,
 "attribute-values"=>{},
 "artist"=>
  {"id"=>"70047e57-0153-4117-b0fc-a1d2e322e5ef",
   "name"=>"Donald Fagen",
   "disambiguation"=>"",
   "sort-name"=>"Fagen, Donald"},
 "ended"=>false,
 "direction"=>"backward",
 "type-id"=>"01ce32b0-d873-4baa-8025-714b45c0c754",
 "begin"=>nil,
 "target-type"=>"artist",
 "target-credit"=>"",
 "type"=>"composer",
 "attributes"=>[],
 "attribute-ids"=>{},
 "source-credit"=>""}
```

I'm trying to get the name from `relations -> artist -> name` if there even is a 'artist' or 'name' and it does not equal nil. How to I approach this? Sorry I'm a Rails newb and just starting to wrestle with data structures. And I assume I'm right in taking care of the data in the backend before sending to React?

**EDIT**

The suggestions below are a lot closer but I still get errors when trying to wrap the data:

```
  def song_details
    search = HTTParty.get("https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release/#{params[:songId]}?inc=artist-credits+artist-rels+media+recording-level-rels+url-rels+work-level-rels+recording-rels&fmt=json", {
      headers: {"User-Agent" => "Songly/ver 1.0", "Contact" => "demiansims@gmail.com"}
      })
      search['relations'].present?
        search['relations'].map do |r|
          r['artist'].present?
          artist = {
            name: r['artist', 'name'],
            role: r['type'].present? && r['type'],
            id: r['artist', 'id'],
            disambiguation: r['artist', 'disambiguation'],
            attributes: r['attributes'] && r['attributes'].each { |a| a }
          }
      end
    artist
  end
```

I get errors like:

```
app/controllers/api/v1/searches_controller.rb:26:in `[]'
app/controllers/api/v1/searches_controller.rb:26:in `block in song_details'
app/controllers/api/v1/searches_controller.rb:21:in `map'
app/controllers/api/v1/searches_controller.rb:21:in `song_details'
```

Comment: is artist an array why are you looping across artist

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example in  which you can use [`Hash#dig`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig)

```
artist_names = search['relations'].map { |r| r.dig('artist', 'name') }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try method in rails try method returns nil is data doest not exist in the object refer to [this](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try) link for reference, If that does not work, use nil checks like `a.present?` or `a.blank?`

If you want to check nil then with the sample you provided and assuming that will be in array you can use

```
a.map { |r|  r['artist'] && r['artist']['name'] } //a is array of object you specified
```

You are doing it wrong r['artist', 'name'] throws an error

```
  def song_details
search = HTTParty.get("https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release/#{params[:songId]}?inc=artist-credits+artist-rels+media+recording-level-rels+url-rels+work-level-rels+recording-rels&fmt=json", {
  headers: {"User-Agent" => "Songly/ver 1.0", "Contact" => "demiansims@gmail.com"}
  })
  search['relations'].present?
    search['relations'].map do |r|
      r['artist'].present?
      artist = {
        name: r.dig('artist', 'name'),
        role: r['type'],
        id: r.dig('artist', 'id'),
        disambiguation: r.dig('artist', 'disambiguation'),
        attributes: r['attributes'] && r['attributes'].each { |a| a }
      }
  end
artist
```

end

Comment: Ok I think both the solutions above are getting a lot closer. If I run just a one liner, the names appear just fine: `search['relations'].map { |r| r['artist'] && r['artist']['name'] }` But if I try to implement a wrapper with necessary protections like `r['artist'].present?`, I still get errors.

Comment: Can you update the answer with updated code and the error you are getting

Comment: Ok yes I did in an EDIT above.

Comment: are you getting `relations` object directly from response???(generally what ever the response you get will be response body not in response)

Comment: @demiansims updated my answer,please  check if it helps